# How to transfer the int[] data from one activity to another activity by using intent

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, integer, int

I have two activities. The first one generates integer arraylist data, I would like to use the data as int[] data in the second activity. My code of the second activity is as follows:

```
public class maptask extends MapActivity {

    @Override


    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }



      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {


        super.onCreate(icicle);
        Intent intent= new Intent();

        List<Integer> x=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("lat");
        List<Integer> y=intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("lon");
        //receive the data from the first activity

        setContentView(R.layout.map);  



        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
        mapoverlay itemizedoverlay = new mapoverlay(drawable, this);

        int a=0, b=0;
        for(a=0; a<x.size();a++)
        //here, the logcat shows there must be something wrong.

            for(b=0; b<y.size(); b++)
            {
                if(a==b)
                {
                    GeoPoint Point =new GeoPoint(x.get(a),y.get(b));

                    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(Point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
                    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
                    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

              }

        }
      }
}
```

In order to find the problems, at first, I tried to define two 2 int[]s at the beginning of the code instead of the arrarylist, and it ran successfully. So the problem must exists in the data type transfer or intent data transfer.

Here below is the first activity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public  List<String> position = new ArrayList<String>(); 
public  List<Long> time=new ArrayList<Long>();
public  List<Integer> lat= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
public  List<Integer> lon= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button mapbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mapbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent =new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, maptask.class);
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lat", (ArrayList<Integer>) lat);
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lon", (ArrayList<Integer>) lon);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", (ArrayList<String>) position);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        final Button listbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        listbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent =new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, list.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", (ArrayList<String>) position);
                //String yes="my name";
                //intent.putExtra("yes", yes);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);


    } 


    private void additem(Location location){
         String latLongString = "Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "\nLong:" + location.getLongitude();
         position.add(latLongString);
         long t=location.getTime();
         time.add(t);

    }

    private void addgeo(Location location){
        int x=(int)location.getLatitude()*1000000;
        int y=(int)location.getLongitude()*1000000;
        lat.add(x);
        lon.add(y);


    }
  //I use the addgeo to put the data into arraylist.    



private  LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          additem(location);
          addgeo(location);

            };
     // updateWithNewLocation(location);


//      addlayout(location);


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      //updateWithNewLocation(null);
  //    addlayout(null);

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //updateWithNewLocation(null);
    //  addlayout(null);

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
  };
```

[image: here below is the logcat screenshot]

Comment: So you are using `putIntegerArrayListExtra` to transfer data?

Comment: Yes, the code is like this:intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lat", (ArrayList<Integer>) lat);
          intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("lon", (ArrayList<Integer>) lon);

Comment: Which line NPE exception happens?

Comment: That is not the correct way to convert integer array to array list.

Comment: I marked in the code above, the first for loop line, and I guess bcuz of the "x.size()" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because in your second Activity

```
 Intent intent= new Intent();
```

It should be

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Comment: yep,u r right. How can I make this stupid mistake. Any way, Many thx!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `int[] lats` you should use:

```
intent.putExtra("lat", lats);
```

And read it with [`getIntArrayExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%5b%5d%29):

```
int[] lats = intent.getIntArrayExtra("lat");
```

Comment: the problem for me is that in the first activity I have to use an integer arraylist to add data, so how to convert the integer arraylist to int array?

Comment: Is is a `List` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: @HeikiCyan `int[]` and `ArrayList<Integer>` are two very different data types... Post the code from your first Activity so we can see what you are working with and how you are using it.

Comment: @HeikiCyan Change all the `List` to `ArrayList`, so you don't need to do the conversion.

Comment: @HeikiCyan See my answer, but still, it is better to declared them as `ArrayList`, so you don't need to cast them.